# what is wrong with the image delivery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've given the relative of the images on my personal portfolio website. but the images failed to load. The console shows the 404 error. In my local machine, the code and the path worked correctly but online the images not loading correctly.[Nabeel Ahmed](https://nabeelahmed1699.github.io/Personal-portfolio-V2/#projects) here is the link to my website.

Comment: with gh-pages you need to take into account the repo name, webroot is not `/` its `/Personal-portfolio-V2/`, i.e https://nabeelahmed1699.github.io/Personal-portfolio-V2/images/projects/weatherapp.png not https://nabeelahmed1699.github.io/images/projects/weatherapp.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In fact ,your img url is "https://nabeelahmed1699.github.io/Personal-portfolio-V2/images/projects/spacewebsite.PNG".

But in your html ,img.src is "https://nabeelahmed1699.github.io/images/projects/Eventcounterapp.png".

Two errors:

1. the suffix of pic is "PNG", not 'png',
2. your resources(imgs,js,css) have a context path (Personal-portfolio-V2)